# Yii2 - Search exact value and return result in detailview

Tags: yii2

I need to put on the page to search by protocol number, and display only one result when the entered protocol number is exactly the same. If possible the results to be shown, it is a DetailView

My model `OccurrenceSearch`:

```
    public function searchprotocol($params)
    {
        $query = Occurrence::find();

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'protocol' => $this->protocol,
        ]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }    
}
```

My view `search`:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

?>

<div class="occurrence-search">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'action' => ['search'],
        'method' => 'get',
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'protocol') ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

My controller `actionSearch()` :

```
public function actionSearch()
{
    $searchModel = new OccurrenceSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->searchprotocol(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('search', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

The guest user can see only the record for its protocol number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The a detailView use model  (and not dataProvider) for show the data instance ..
then  in you controller you should obtain the model

```
public function actionSearch()
{
    $searchModel = new OccurrenceSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->searchprotocol(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $model = $dataProvider->query->one();

    return $this->render('search', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        //'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

But in you view the code proposed don't show a detailView widget ..  you should probably add

Comment: It worked, but how to make the DetailView come initially empty? (Is showing the latest record)

Comment: how do you know if it is the initial run or subsequent execution?

Comment: to enter the search page, it already displays the last record.
The logic is the so visitors can see the information related to its protocol. He types the number and the system displays the DetailView (or grid) for the number.

Comment: OK .. How i can know that the action is called for the first time and not a subsequent one ? .. the search param  are empty?

Comment: yes, the same happens if I click SEARCH me without typing anything

Comment: If you enter a value that does not exist, appears "Please specify the" model "property."

Comment: I decided to use the same GRIDVIEW, and so changed the modelsearch

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use the GRIDVIEW, and so changed the MymodelSearch

if (isset($_GET['AuthorSearch']) && !($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
    return $dataProvider;
}